# How to add a border to fpar in Officer R

Tags: r, docx, officer

I am trying to use the `Officer` package to create a `docx`. I want to create paragraphs with different levels and text styles while also having each paragraph have its own border. I have tried using `fp_par` with both a `block_list` command and a `fpar` command but with no luck. Any ideas? Here is what I have been trying:

```
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

reg24 <- fp_text(color = "black", font.size = 24)
bold <- fp_text(color = "black", font.size = 24, bold = TRUE)
underline <- fp_text(color = "black", font.size = 24, underlined = TRUE)
bigbold <- fp_text(color = "black", font.size = 28, bold = TRUE)
border <- fp_par(
  text.align = "left",
  padding = 0,
  border = fp_border(color = "black", style = "solid", width = 1))

summary <- block_list(
fpar(ftext("9", bigbold),
         ftext("Address", bold))%>%
    fpar(ftext("Status:", underline),
         ftext("Under Construction", reg24))%>%
    fpar(ftext("Expected Completion:", underline),
         ftext("2020", reg24))%>%
    fpar(ftext("Investment:", underline),
         ftext("$2,000,000")))
```

I'm not sure where to go from here because it doesn't seem like there is a way to have a paragraph with different levels, different text styles, *and* a border. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example:

```
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

img.file <- file.path( R.home("doc"), "html", "logo.jpg" )
fpt_blue_bold <- fp_text(color = "#006699", bold = TRUE)
fpt_red_italic <- fp_text(color = "#C32900", italic = TRUE)

border <- fp_par(
  text.align = "left",
  padding = 0,
  border.bottom = fp_border(color = "red", style = "solid", width = 1))

value <- block_list(
  fpar(ftext("hello world", fpt_blue_bold), fp_p = border),
  fpar(ftext("hello", fpt_blue_bold), " ", ftext("world", fpt_red_italic))
)


read_docx() %>% 
  body_add_blocks(value) %>% 
  print(target = "coco.docx")
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for your help, David, and for the `Officer` package!